# Angular Update more efficient way to update text input value

Tags: angular, typescript, input

I'm updating an angular application to work on older machines and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to update a text input field other than (keyup), where it updates on each keystroke. I can't find anything that requires fewer requests.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You use ReactiveForms with rxjs :

```js
form: FormControl = new FormControl();

ngOnInit() {
  this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(1000), // delay until the user stops typing
    switchMap(value => {
      return this.http....
      })
  ).subscribe();
}
```

In your template :

```
<input [formControl]="formControl">
```

And add `ReactiveFormsModule` into the imports array of your ngModule.

Comment: How would I assign this to the input value? What is currently there is (keyup)="update($event)

Comment: just remove the keyup part and add the formControl directive

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReactiveFormsModule

```
    const inputControl = new FormControl();

    inputControl.valueChanges.pipe(
        debounceTime(500)
    ).subscribe(value => {
        // use input value
    });

<input [formControl]="inputControl" />
```